500 Error with Spring Cloud Gateway Routing via Eureka Service Discovery - Heroku Deployment
I'm working with a set of microservices that are all part of the Spring Cloud ecosystem, that are all deployed on Heroku cloud. There is a discovery server microservice that hosts 2 other microservices, one being a gateway service that does the routing and another service which is mostly for the primary business workflows. Each of the services are successfully deployed on Heroku and Heroku has provided me the URL for each service. The only issue is, when I try to use the gateway service to route the API requests, I get a 500 error response.
Environment:

Spring Cloud
Netflix Eureka Server and client
Heroku deployment

Problem:

Direct requests to the ct-cryptography-core-lib service work fine:

GET https://example-service.herokuapp.com/rest/symmetric/block-cipher/encryption/
But, routing through the gateway results in errors:
GET https://example-gateway-service.herokuapp.com/core-service/rest/symmetric/block-cipher/encryption/
Results in:
{
  "timestamp": "<timestamp of the error>",
  "path": "/<service-path>",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "requestId": "<request ID>"
}

**
Configuration (Gateway application.properties):**
server.port=${PORT}
spring.application.name=ct-api-gateway-service
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true

# Eureka client settings
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=https://<discovery-service-url>/eureka/

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

# LOGGING INFO:
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionLocator=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud=DEBUG

# -- ct-cryptography-core-lib Route: --
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=ct-cryptography-core-lib
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://ct-cryptography-core-lib
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/rest/symmetric/block-cipher/encryption/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Path=/rest/symmetric/block-cipher/decryption/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[2]=Path=/rest/hash/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[3]=Path=/rest/hash/subProcess/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[4]=Path=/rest/authentication/process/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[5]=Path=/rest/encryption/subProcess/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[6]=Path=/rest/symmetric/key/process/**

Configuration (ct-cryptography-core-lib):
server.port=${PORT}
spring.application.name=ct-cryptography-core-lib
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=https://<discovery-service-url>/eureka/

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true

Configuration (ct-discovery-server):
server.port=${PORT}
eureka.instance.hostname=<discovery-server-hostname>
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=https://<discovery-service-url>/eureka/
spring.application.name=ct-discovery-server

logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionLocator=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=TRACE

I played around with spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri configurations between direct URLs and service discovery via lb://
Questions:

What might be causing these 500 errors when routing through the gateway?
Are there any common pitfalls with Eureka integration and routing that I should check?
How can I ensure that the gateway correctly resolves service routes registered with Eureka?

Errors in Heroku Gateway Logs:
When making the following API call through the gateway:
GET https:///CT-CRYPTOGRAPHY-CORE-LIB/rest/symmetric/block-cipher/encryption/
I receive a 500 Internal Server Error. The logs suggest an issue with DNS resolution:
2024-06-14T01:50:30.086Z ERROR 2 --- [or-http-epoll-5] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [8079cc1d-3]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/CT-CRYPTOGRAPHY-CORE-LIB/rest/symmetric/block-cipher/encryption/"
io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$SearchDomainUnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'xxxxxx.prvt.dyno.rt.heroku.com' [A(1)] and search domain query for configured domains failed as well: [ec2.internal]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1097) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.97.Final.jar!/:4.1.97.Final]
I think this error indicates that there is a failure in resolving the hostname generated by Heroku, which might be an internal DNS issue.
The Eureka dashboard shows both services as successfully registered with Eureka with a status of up.
When I try to access the Gateway service URL, I get a whitelabel error on my browser.
Thank you!
Tried many different configurations.
